# ng-init for input type 'text' does not show any data inside textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textbox, angularjs-ng-model

### html

```
                        <div class="form-inline col-xs-12"  ng-repeat="c in evnetChannels track by $index">
                            <label class="control-label col-xs-6">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       ng-checked="ChannelisChecked(c.channelTypeId)"
                                       ng-click="ChannelToggleCheckbox(c.channelTypeId, $event)">
                                {{c.channelTypeName}}
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control col-xs-6" type="text" ng-show="c.textRequired=='Y'" ng-init="comment=getComment(c.channelTypeId)" ng-model="comment"
                                   ng-disabled="!ChannelisChecked(c.channelTypeId)" ng-change="setComment(comment,c.channelTypeId)">
                        </div>
```

### javascript

```
$scope.ChannelisChecked = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
    var chnl = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
        return channel.channelTypeId == val;
    });
    if(chnl){
        return chnl.isChecked =="Y";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

$scope.getComment = function (id) {
        console.log('here');
        var chnl = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
            return channel.channelTypeId == id;
        });
        if(chnl){
            console.log(chnl);
            return chnl.comments;
        }
        else {
            console.log('none');
            return null;
        }
    };

    $scope.ChannelToggleCheckbox = function (val, event) {

        var check_true = event.target.checked;
        console.log(val);
        var found = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
            return channel.channelTypeId == val;
        });
        if(!found && check_true){
            var newSelection = _.clone(channel);
            newSelection.channelTypeId = val;
            $scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList.push(newSelection);
        }
        else if (found && !check_true){
            $scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList = _.without($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, _.findWhere($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList,{channelTypeId:val}));
        }
    };



$scope.evnetChannels = [{
      "channelTypeId": 1,
      "channelTypeName": "c1",
      "textRequired": "Y",
      "action": "Y"
    },
    {
      "channelTypeId": 2,
      "channelTypeName": "c2",
      "textRequired": "Y"
    },
    {
      "channelTypeId": 3,
      "channelTypeName": "c3",
      "textRequired": "N"
    }];

$scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList = [{
     "channelTypeId": 1,
     "isChecked": "Y",
     "comments" : "hello"

},
{
     "channelTypeId": 3,
     "isChecked": "Y"
 }];
```

So I am having issue that the code, on the html checkboxes are selected properly, text "hello" should be displayed inside the text box next to checkbox labeled "c1" but text box is coming empty.

any issues with this code?

Comment: your doing `ng-repeat` with the same scope model `ng-model="comment"` if one of your data returned empty the expected behavior your `inputs` will also be empty

Comment: and i think you can try using [check here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) `ng-value` rather than `ng-init`

Comment: thanks, i have no explanation my code doesn't work, but good alternatives that work for me

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your code in a plunk, and I could not re-produce the error. The only change I made was to initialize formData_EventDescription before setting .eventChannelList because it was throwing me errors.

See the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PWS47zHBWnoBChk3jCrD?p=preview)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
     <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <div class="form-inline col-xs-12"  ng-repeat="c in evnetChannels track by $index">
                            <label class="control-label col-xs-6">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       ng-checked="ChannelisChecked(c.channelTypeId)"
                                       ng-click="ChannelToggleCheckbox(c.channelTypeId, $event)">
                                {{c.channelTypeName}}
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control col-xs-6" type="text" ng-show="c.textRequired=='Y'" ng-init="comment=getComment(c.channelTypeId)" ng-model="comment"
                                   ng-disabled="!ChannelisChecked(c.channelTypeId)" ng-change="setComment(comment,c.channelTypeId)">
                        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.ChannelisChecked = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
    var chnl = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
        return channel.channelTypeId == val;
    });
    if(chnl){
        return chnl.isChecked =="Y";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

$scope.getComment = function (id) {
        console.log('here');
        var chnl = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
            return channel.channelTypeId == id;
        });
        if(chnl){
            console.log(chnl);
            return chnl.comments;
        }
        else {
            console.log('none');
            return null;
        }
    };

    $scope.ChannelToggleCheckbox = function (val, event) {

        var check_true = event.target.checked;
        console.log(val);
        var found = _.find($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, function (channel) {
            return channel.channelTypeId == val;
        });
        if(!found && check_true){
            var newSelection = _.clone(channel);
            newSelection.channelTypeId = val;
            $scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList.push(newSelection);
        }
        else if (found && !check_true){
            $scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList = _.without($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList, _.findWhere($scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList,{channelTypeId:val}));
        }
    };



$scope.evnetChannels = [{
      "channelTypeId": 1,
      "channelTypeName": "c1",
      "textRequired": "Y",
      "action": "Y"
    },
    {
      "channelTypeId": 2,
      "channelTypeName": "c2",
      "textRequired": "Y"
    },
    {
      "channelTypeId": 3,
      "channelTypeName": "c3",
      "textRequired": "N"
    }];

$scope.formData_EventDescription = {};

$scope.formData_EventDescription.eventChannelList = [{
     "channelTypeId": 1,
     "isChecked": "Y",
     "comments" : "hello"

},
{
     "channelTypeId": 3,
     "isChecked": "Y"
 }];


});
```

Comment: yea same code doesn't work for me :( only thing i would ask is why is method ChannelisChecked being so many times, if you observe the console.log is this a defect or am i doing something wrong

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. Looks like it should only be getting called 6 times. You have 2 calls within your ng-repeat. So that's 2 calls for each iteration with a total of 3 items = 6. Not sure what is firing it again. May have something to do with the way Angular uses [watchers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)